# How can I get ChatGPT to enforce syntax rules when converting code between languages?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design, computer-programming, chatgpt-3.5

The goal is to convert Python to MATLAB while preserving `a=1` keyword argument syntax (standard is `'a', 1`).

**Worked**: a bunch of code-related prompts in the same session, followed by

> From now on, when converting code that uses function calls, preserve the `=` syntax - for example, keep `criterion_amplitude=criterion_amplitude`as-is and don't change it to `'criterion_amplitude', criterion_amplitude`.

**Doesn't work**:

> User
> I will paste Python code, and you provide its MATLAB equivalent. When converting function calls, preserve the `=` syntax - for example, keep `fast=true` as-is and don't change it to `'fast', true`.

**Doesn't work**: **"Worked"** but in a new session.

**Doesn't work**: continuing the **"Worked"** session next day.

What's a reliable way to enforce arbitrary syntax rules?

#### A complete transcript

No matter how clearly I explain things or how many times I regenerate the output, nothing changes.

[image]

Comment: Tags should not be included in the title. Ref. https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/tagging